# reset bios password with cmospwd, ioperm startservice function call failed

Tags: laptop, bios, acer-aspire, cmos

I've been trying to reset the bios password on an old Acer Aspire laptop. I've been looking for a while until I stumbled upon cmospwd. I downloaded it, and it asked me to "run ioperm -i as administrator first" Upon running ioperm -i, I received a message stating "StartService function call failed". I couldn't find anything helpful on this error, so I decided to come here. I did find some info from replies on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/406940/i-need-to-reset-a-bios-password-using-software-on-windows-7) post, in response to someone stating that they got the same error as me. They said they tried running ioperm manually with net start, but it said system error 2, system cannot find the file specified. Someone responded to this stated that ioperm is 32-bit only and my only other option would be to run it off a Live CD of Linux, but I'm pretty sure my laptop is 32-bit, and the reason why I need into the bios is to enable the Boot Device option, so using a Live CD is out of the question.

If you need some info about the laptop, It's currently running Windows 7, and is the Acer Aspire 5534 series. The only other problems are that Windows states that my battery is old and that I should replace it, but besides that the laptop runs fine.

If cmospwd isn't an option, what other software/options do I have? I'd prefer not to do anything physical to the laptop remove the bios password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by flashing a new BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a lost CMOS password from an ACER computer:

1. Boot while while pressing/holding <kbd>F2</kbd> to get into the BIOS/UEFI
2. When the enter password window appears then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> three times
3. An "Enter unlock password" window will appear, with something like "Key: 45454545"
4. Take a note of that key
5. Go to [BiOSBUG.com](https://www.biosbug.com/acer/),
   enter that key into search field and press the "Send Request" button
   and get the Acer bios unlock key
6. Go back to your laptop and enter that code into the "Enter Unlock Password" box
   and if successful you should now be inside the BIOS
7. Go to the Security tab and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on "Set Supervisor Password"
   and a little box with three password fields should pop up
8. Enter your unlock key from BiOSBUG.com into the first field which is the
   current password field, leaving the "New password field" and "Confirm field" blank
   (hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> two times)
9. Now navigate to the Exit tab and press on "Exit Saving Changes"
10. Your laptop should have no BIOS password anymore.

Comment: I've already tried this, there is no "Key: 45454545". All it says after pressing enter 3 times is "System will halt!"

Comment: Unfortunate. Have you tried the remove CMOS battery trick?

Comment: No, because I've seen on posts that it doesn't work sometimes and I don't want to do anything physical to my device unless I really have to.

Comment: There aren't too many ways for removing a BIOS password ...

Comment: Alright, I'll try taking the battery out, how long should I leave it out?

Comment: At least five minutes.

Comment: I was going to take out the battery, but it was too complicated and required me to take apart almost the entire laptop to access the battery.